# This syntax doesn't work with the syntax of Angular's dependency injection, how do I fix this?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm sure that this is an easy fix, but I just can't get it sorted out.

I have a app file, a routes file and a config file. Here's each one:

The App File:

```
(function () {
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('app', [
      'app.config',
      'app.routes',
      'app.authentication'
    ]);

  angular
    .module('app.config', [
      'restangular',
      'ngAnimate',
      'ngMaterial'
    ]);

  angular
    .module('app.routes', ['ui.router']);

})();
```

The Routes file:

```
(function () {
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('app.routes')
    .config(config);

  config.$inject = ['ui.router'];

  function config($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");

    $stateProvider
      .state('register', {
        url:"/register",
        controller: 'RegisterController',
        controllerAs: 'register',
        templateUrl: "/static/templates/authentication/register.html"
      })
      .state('', {
        url:"/",
        templateUrl: "/static/templates/landing.html"
      });
  }

})();
```

The Config file:

```
(function () {
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('app.config')
    .config(config);

  config.$inject = [
    'restangular',
    'ngAnimate',
    'ngMaterial'
  ];

  function config($locationProvider, $uiViewScrollProvider, RestangularProvider, $mdThemingProvider, $mdIconProvider) {
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    $locationProvider.hashPrefix('!');

    RestangularProvider.setBaseUrl('/api/');
    RestangularProvider.setDefaultHttpFields({xsrfCookieName:'csrftoken', xsrfHeaderName:'X-CSRFToken'});

    $uiViewScrollProvider.useAnchorScroll();

    $mdThemingProvider.theme('default').primaryPalette('blue').accentPalette('pink');

    $mdIconProvider.fontSet('fa', 'fontawesome');
  }

})();
```

And then in my index file I'm including them like so:

```
<script src="{% static 'app/app.config.js' %}" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="{% static 'app/app.routes.js' %}" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="{% static 'app/app.js' %}" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

The error that I'm getting is:

```
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'app.routes' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.2/$injector/nomod?p0=app.routes
```

and

```
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'app.config' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.2/$injector/nomod?p0=app.config
```

The weird thing is they are the abbreviated errors, not the normal really long error when I screw up injection in the past.

Comment: more verbose errors are available when you don't use minified version of angular

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to use the modules before declaring them in your script. You would need to reorder the scripts loaded, i.e `app.js` needs to be loaded before `app.config.js` and `app.routes.js`.

```
<!-- This comes first before the files that uses it-->
<script src="{% static 'app/app.js' %}" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="{% static 'app/app.config.js' %}" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="{% static 'app/app.routes.js' %}" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Or move the declarations of config and routes to its own files respectively.

```
 //in app.config.js, declare its module
  angular
    .module('app.config', [
      'restangular',
      'ngAnimate',
      'ngMaterial'
    ]);

  //app.routes.js
  angular
    .module('app.routes', ['ui.router']);
```

Well you got more issues: You cannot **`inject`** a module, you can only list them as dependency in module declaration. Instead you inject the module's services, providers, controllers etc.. with $inject annotation of array annotation so that they are minification safe.

So you would need to change:

```
config.$inject = ['ui.router'];
```

to

```
config.$inject = ['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider'];
```

and

```
config.$inject = [
    'restangular',
    'ngAnimate',
    'ngMaterial'
  ];
```

to

```
config.$inject = [
  '$locationProvider', 
  '$uiViewScrollProvider', 
  'RestangularProvider', 
  '$mdThemingProvider', 
  '$mdIconProvider'

];
```

I am not sure what other (actual) errors will pop out after you fix this. But if you follow the error message you should be able to fix them. Most Angular error messages are very descriptive (if not use non-minified in dev mode to see more descriptive errors) also have a good read on **[dependency injection](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di)** before using it.

Comment: That isn't working either. When I change the order, I'm getting much bigger inclusion errors.

Comment: @DaveMerwin That must be the real errors. What is the error, do you mind adding the error message here in the comment? Also inspect your network to see if the file paths are proper and are being loaded properly or not. Basic idea is that you cannot do `angular
    .module('a').controller...` before `angular.module('a',[])` because module `a` does not exist yet.

Comment: @DaveMerwin there are more issues what did you mean by `config.$inject = ['ui.router'];` ? `ui.router` is a module you cannot inject it. Same is the case with config file inject as well.

Comment: Ahhhh! I get it now. First, you have to define the module and include it's dependencies and then you need to inject what you need from the dependencies for the module when you build the config! That is pretty dang cool. Thanks for everyone's help and time!

Answer (score 0):

The second parameter to define a angular's module is required.

```
angular.module('app.config', []);
```

Also, you are defining the `app.config` and `app.routing` modules twice. One in `app.js` and other in `app.config.js`and `app.routing.js` respectively.

If you run `angular.module('app.config', []);` in the console you will get the same error you posted.

```
Error: [$injector:nomod]....
```

Comment: I guess you are wrong when you said `you are defining the app.config and app.routing modules twice`. OP is not, `angular.module('a',[])` is module creation, not `angular.module('a')` which is a getter.